# Holoviews DynamicMap Area or Curve with two streams is showing wrong chart

Tags: python, stream, holoviews

I would like to use HoloViews DynamicMap with a widget to select data for two curves, and a widget to control whether the curves are shown separately or as a filled area.  It almost works, but sometimes shows the wrong data, depending on the order in which the widgets are manipulated.

The code snippet below demonstrates the issue, if run in a Jupyter notebook. It creates two identical DynamicMaps to show how they get out of sync with the widgets.

- For this demo, if 'fill', an Area chart is shown.  Otherwise, two Curve elements show the top and bottom bounds of the same area.
- If 'higher', the area or curves are shifted upwards along the vertical axis (higher y values).
- First, one DynamicMap is displayed. The code snippet then toggles the widget for 'fill' followed by 'higher', in that order (alternatively, the user could manually toggle the widgets). The DynamicMap should show a filled area in the higher position, but actually shows a filled area in the lower position. The image below the code snippet shows this incorrect DynamicMap on the left.
- The second DynamicMap (shown on the right) is added to the display after the widgets are toggled. It correctly displays a chart corresponding to the state of the widgets at that point.

## Code snippet

```
    import holoviews as hv
    import numpy as np
    import panel as pn
    
    pn.extension()
    
    # Make two binary widgets to control whether chart
    # data is high or low, and whether chart shows
    # an area fill or just a pair of lines.
    check_boxes = {name: pn.widgets.Checkbox(value=False, name=name) \
                   for name in ["higher", "fill"]}
    
    # Data for charts.
    xvals = [0.10, 0.90]
    yvals_high = [1, 1.25]
    yvals_low = [0.25, 0.40]
    
    # Declare horizontal and vertical dimensions to go on charts.
    xdim = hv.Dimension("x", range=(-0.5, 1.5), label="xdim")
    ydim = hv.Dimension("y", range=(0, 2), label="ydim")
    
    def make_plot(higher, fill):
        """Make high or low, filled area or line plot"""
        yvals_line1 = np.array(yvals_high if higher else yvals_low)
        yvals_line2 = 1.2*yvals_line1
            
        if fill:
            # Make filled area plot with x series and two y series.
            area_data = (xvals, yvals_line1, yvals_line2)
            plot = hv.Area(area_data,
                           kdims=xdim, 
                           vdims=[ydim, ydim.clone("y.2")])
            plot = hv.Overlay([plot])  # DMap will want an overlay.
        else:
            # Make line plot with x series and y series.
            line_data_low = (xvals, yvals_line1)
            line_data_high = (xvals, yvals_line2)
    
            plot = hv.Curve(line_data_low, 
                            kdims=xdim, 
                            vdims=ydim) \
                * hv.Curve(line_data_high, 
                            kdims=xdim, 
                            vdims=ydim)
        return plot
    
    # Map combinations of higher and fill to corresponding charts.
    chart_dict = {(higher, fill): make_plot(higher, fill) \
                  for higher in [False,True] for fill in [False,True]}
    
    def chart_func(higher, fill):
        """Return chart from chart_dict lookup"""
        return chart_dict[higher, fill]
    
    # Make two DynamicMaps linked to the check boxes.
    dmap1 = hv.DynamicMap(chart_func, kdims=["higher", "fill"], streams=check_boxes)
    dmap2 = hv.DynamicMap(chart_func, kdims=["higher", "fill"], streams=check_boxes)
    
    # Show the check boxes, and one of the DMaps.
    widget_row = pn.Row(*check_boxes.values(), width=150)
    dmap_row = pn.Row(dmap1, align='start')
    
    layout = pn.Column(widget_row,
                        dmap_row)
    display(layout)
    ## Optionally use following line to launch a server, then toggle widgets.
    #layout.show()
    
    
    # Toggle 'fill' and then 'higher', in that order.  
    # Both DMaps should track widgets...
    check_boxes["fill"].value = True
    check_boxes["higher"].value = True
    
    # Show the other DMap, which displays correctly given the current widgets.
    dmap_row.append(dmap2)
    
    # But first dmap (left) is now showing an area in wrong location.
```

## Notebook display

[image: Two DMaps showing filled area charts. Left chart incorrectly shows filled area in lower position. Right chart correctly shows filled area in higher position.]

## Further widget toggles

The code snippet below can be run immediately afterwards in another cell. The resulting notebook display is shown in an image below the code snippet.

- The code here toggles the widgets again, 'fill' and 'higher', in that order (alternatively, the user could manually toggle the widgets).
- The left DynamicMap correctly displays a chart corresponding to the state of the widgets at that point, that is, two lines in the lower position.
- The right DynamicMap incorrectly shows the two lines in the higher position.

```
# Toggle 'fill' and then 'higher' again, in that order.  
# Both DMaps should track widgets...
check_boxes["fill"].value = False
check_boxes["higher"].value = False

# But now the second DMap shows lines in wrong location.
```

[image: Two DMaps showing line charts. Left chart correctly shows lines in lower position. Right chart correctly shows lines in higher position.]

Am I just going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the detailed, reproducible report!

After running your example, I noticed two things:

1. Switching from `pn.extension` to `hv.extension` at the start seems to fix the strange behavior that I also observing when using the panel extension. Could you confirm that things work as expected when using the holoviews extension?
2. I was wondering why your `DynamicMap`s work via `chart_dict` and `chart_func` when you can just use your `make_plot` callback in the `DynamicMap`s directly, without modification.

If you can confirm that the extension used changes the behavior, could you file an [issue](https://github.com/holoviz/panel/issues) about this? Thanks!

Comment: Using `hv.extension` either instead of or in addition to `pn.extension` seems to avoid the strange behavior.  Good spot!  If they worked properly, would one ever need one rather than the other, or both rather than one?

Comment: On (2), yes ordinarily `DynamicMap` would just use `make_plot()` directly.  The `chart_dict` is included here for debugging to make it easy to verify that `make_plot()` isn't inducing the odd behavior.